# How to split a string and then split the returned value again connected to another value that has to be split, and join the remainder to the remaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

What I want is something like a string that is around 2000 to 3000 characters with over a hundred non-uniformly located `\n` in them, and I want to split them for every 1000 characters, and then in the returned strings in an array, for each of the values in the returned array, I want to end the string at the last `\n` (leaves it as it is if the string contains no `\n`) and the remainder of the string after the last `\n` should be appended to the beginning of the next value in the array, and then this should be carried out AFTER the previous string has been fixed to the last `\n`

I hope you understand what I mean, and this is my code

```js
module.exports={
    async split(text,length,max){
        if (text.length > max){
            return;
        }
        let regex = new RegExp(`.{1,${length}}`, "g");
        let splitted = text.match(regex);
        return splitted;
    }
}
```

The place where its fetched and executed is here:

```js
        let splitted = await split(lyrics,1000,6000)
```

I managed to do the split for every 1000 words but the thing that I explained at the top is what I want to do and I am unable to manage it, so can anyone help out?

EDIT: Suppose I wanted to split the string for a max of 20 characters with the max string length of 1000, and if it bypasses that limit, then it means that nothing will be returned. It can do that second stage of splitting (as I mentioned in the question as `\n`) with a whitespace ( ).
Imagine that the string is: `Hello, I love Stack Overflow, and it is super cool`
In my current code, if we did

```js
let string = `Hello, I love Stack Overflow, and it is super cool`
let splitted = await split(string, 10, 1000)
```

It would return

`["Hello, I l", "ove Stack ", "Overflow, ", "and it is ", "super cool"]`

What if another agument is added in `split()`, making it:

`async split(text, length, max, splitAt)`

`splitAt` can mean `\n` or   depending on choice

The result that I want to return is: `["Hello, I", "love Stack", "Overflow,", "and it is", "super cool"]`

The thing is, I can not understand how to do it

Comment: Can you edit your post to include examples of given inputs and expected outputs? Let's say for the example that you want 10 instead of 1000 and 20 for 2000, etc.

Comment: done, made it look a lot better and made code more refined

Comment: Just saw your updated question. Do you want to be able to specify the character they're split on, such as ` ` or `\n`.

Comment: for a start there is absolutely no need for this to be `async`. Also, your example input/output makes no sense - there are no `\n` in it which seems rather fundamental to the question! Thirdly your code doesnt do what you think it does [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7xec6awz/)

Comment: @Jamiec ohh right sorry forgot that. 
as for the third thing, i wrote a parameter wrong. and about the input/output, in the expectation i specified that instead of \n, I cleared it up using a whitespace for it, which I defined by `splitAt`

Comment: @Invizi I mean, it would be best to be able to specify through function arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly don't need this method to be `async` and it should just be a case of stepping through the string, splitting by `len` and finding the `lastIndexOf` your `splitAt` argument, and then taking that chunk into an array using `substring`

Something like this:

```js
function split(text, len, max, splitAt) {
  if (text.length > max) {
    return;
  }

  let pos = 0;
  const chunks = []
  while (pos < text.length) {
    if (pos + len >= text.length) {
      chunks.push(text.substring(pos));
      pos = text.length
    } else {
      const s = text.substring(pos, pos + len + 1).lastIndexOf(splitAt);
      chunks.push(text.substring(pos, pos + s));
      pos += s + 1;
    }
  }
  return chunks;

}

let string = `Hello, I love Stack Overflow, and it is super cool`
let splitted = split(string, 10, 1000, " ")
console.log(splitted);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to split the text into chunks that have a max size of 1000, and they should end with a newline character.

```
function split(str, chunkSize){
    const chunks = [];
    let current_chunk = ""
    str.split("\n").forEach(part => {
        if(current_chunk.length + part.length > chunkSize){
            // Adds the chunk to chunks and resets current chunk.
            chunks.push(current_chunk);
            current_chunk = "";
        }
        // adds \n to the start of the part, if the current chunk isn't empty.
        current_chunk.length 
           ? current_chunk += `\n${part}`
           : current_chunk += part
    })
    // Used to get the last one, if it isn't empty.
    if(current_chunk.length) chunks.push(current_chunk);
    return chunks;
}
```

Should look something like this. Haven't tested it though, since I've written it on my phone.

Comment: it splits at every \n, not the last one for each of the strings